# How can I get this result using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have two tables: a table of *Users* and a table of *Votes*. The Votes table stores a record that contains the Id of a user.

As a simple example, let's say my Users table has the following fields:

```
UserId, Name, Age, Gender
```

And my Votes table has:

```
UserId, DateCreated
```

What I want to do is **select the top 10 users that have the highest votes.**

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: What does your query look like so far? And what exactly does "highest votes" mean?

Comment: This is the problem: I haven't managed to find anything through searching because my description of the problem is so verbose. I don't know where to turn! Heck, if someone could even point me in the rough direction of what I should be searching for that'd be very helpful

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but you don't appear to be storing the number of votes anywhere. Your tables make no sense in relation to your question.

Comment: So your Votes-tables has only one field `UserId`?

Comment: Apologies, the fields were incorrect - now it should make more sense

Comment: @大师燈XiHuan I figured that. Just misread it at first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Context.Users.OrderByDescending(x => x.Votes.Count()).Take(10)
```

Comment: I think it should be `OrderByDescending`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've got navigation properties set up between your tables, you could do this:

```
var results = db.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Votes.Count()).Take(10);
```

This will find the top 10 users with the greatest number of votes.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have foreign keys/property mapped:

```
  var query = (from u in db.Users
              join v in (
               from v in db.Votes
               group v by v.UserId into grp
               select new {
                 UserId = grp.Key,
                 Count = grp.Count()
               }) on u.Id equals v.UserId into l_vset
              from l_v in l_vset.DefaultIfEmpty()
              orderby l_v == null ? 0 : l_v.Count descending
              select new {
                User = u,
                Votes = l_v == null ? 0 : l_v.Count
              }).Take(10);
```